# How do I overwrite config settings from an included file

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe-config

I have defined some akka remote settings in my application.conf:

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
        warn-about-java-serializer-usage = false
    }
    remote {
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
        netty.tcp {
            hostname = "myhost"
            port = 2561
            maximum-frame-size = 256000b
        }
    }
}
```

But then I have another program that needs to access other configuration settings from my application.conf. But I need to ignore the akka config settings. So I've tried the following for the second program:

```
include "application"

akka {}
```

But the akka settings from application.conf are still being applied. I know this because I get a bind exception on the akka port eventhough there should be no remote akka in my second app

What is the best way for me clear/ignore the akka config settings from my application.conf?

Comment: Does any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to override the akka.remote.netty.tcp.port in your `another.conf`, you simply

```
include "application.conf"

akka.remote.netty.tcp.port = 2562
```

It will override the netty tcp port while leaving the rest unchanged and inherited

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, the best bet IMO is to factor out your `application.conf` so that your common settings are in their own `conf` files.

So you might put the common settings in a `common-settings.conf` and then in your Akka application you would have

```
include "common-settings"

akka {
  // Akka settings here
}
```

And the other modules that need `common-settings` can just, in their `application.conf`:

```
include "common-settings"
```

This may work better with a multi-module build.  If they're the same, e.g., sbt module, then you'll probably replace the canonical `application.conf` with `akka-application.conf` and `other-application.conf` and point your `ActorSystem` setup code to `akka-application.conf` instead of `application.conf` (which probably shouldn't exist in this scenario, as you'd want bare `ConfigFactory.load()` calls to fail very quickly (the alternative here is to have different programs fighting over who owns `application.conf`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is actually by design. From the [HOCON first page documentation](https://github.com/lightbend/config#features-of-hocon):

> Duplicate keys are allowed; later values override earlier, except for object-valued keys where the two objects are merged recursively

Therefore, when you add in your second file an `akka {}` it is just being merged, and not overwritten.

As I can see it, you have 2 options.

1. Copying the configuration, and override all properties with the one you actually want. That means, that in the second program, you can add:

   ```
   akka {
       actor {
           provider = "new value"
           warn-about-java-serializer-usage = false
       }
       remote {
           enabled-transports = ["completely new values"]
           netty.tcp {
               hostname = "etc..."
               port = 2561
               maximum-frame-size = 256000b
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. The other option, which I like less, is to overwrite the object called akka. For doing that, you need to assign to it something that is not an object. Otherwise it will just be merged. For instance, if you add the the second program `akka=4`, so it will completely remove all of the other values. **But**! In this case, you have your program to deal with those properties to be missing. That means, that somewhere in your code you will have to write something like (don't forget that `config` throws on missing):

   ```
   Try(config.getString("akka.actor.provider")).getOrElse(Do something here)
   ```

   You have to do that because now akka is a string, and you cannot look into that as an object.